# Restrict youtube video access through API

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api

I am working on a web application where users will register with my application and be able to see certain videos uploaded only for this registered audience. I would personally prefer a video-specialist website like youtube.

Now, can we add users through youtube API who will be allowed to watch these videos. If not, then please suggest a good video hosting service that will allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Vimeo, which allows more privacy and restriction options

Comment: I was long ago working on a project that required an answer to this. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark a video as private, public, or unlisted via the API.

You can't add/remove specific accounts to the access-control list of who's allowed to view a private video using the API, though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do I have any alternatives in terms of video hosting websites?